# Barcode not showing in PDF

Tags: javascript, html, xslt

So I used [This JS Library](https://github.com/bkuzmic/pdf417-js) to generate a barcode. This works perfectly fine on the web. But when I then transform the document to PDF, using [this site](https://www.nrecosite.com/pdf_generator_net.aspx) , only the value of the barcode shows up... Not sure what to do anymore as I've looked almost everywhere and tried different methods but no progress, yet. Please assist/advice where you can? Thanks.

Here's my xsl/html code

```
<!-- Get barcode value in xml and strip the html tags -->
            <div id="strip">
                <xsl:value-of select="ReportData/StartRep/BarCode" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
            </div>

        <!--  Display Barcode -->
            <div class="barcode" id="barcode"></div>
```

My JavaScript code :

```
  window.onload = function () {
  let textToEncode = document.getElementById("strip").textContent;

  PDF417.init(textToEncode.value);

  let barcode = PDF417.getBarcodeArray();

  // block sizes (width and height) in pixels
  let bw = 2;
  let bh = 2;

  // create canvas element based on number of columns and rows in barcode
  let container = document.getElementById("barcode");
  container.removeChild(container.firstChild);

  let canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  canvas.width = bw * barcode["num_cols"];
  canvas.height = bh * barcode["num_rows"];
  container.appendChild(canvas);

  let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

  // graph barcode elements
  let y = 0;
  // for each row
  for (let r = 0; r < barcode["num_rows"]; ++r) {
    let x = 0;
    // for each column
    for (let c = 0; c < barcode["num_cols"]; ++c) {
      if (barcode["bcode"][r][c] == 1) {
        ctx.fillRect(x, y, bw, bh);
      }
      x += bw;
    }
    y += bh;
  }
};

document.getElementById("strip").style.display = "none";
```

Comment: "But when I then transform the document to PDF": how exactly do you perform that step, which tools do you use to "transform the (HTML document rendered in the browser?) to PDF"?

Comment: @MartinHonnen I just edited the question and placed a link to the site. Thanks

Comment: If you have problems with one particular software being promoted as a tool to create PDF from HTML I would suggest to contact the authors of the software. And where does XSLT come into play? Does a Canvas contained, JavaScript generated barcode show up in the PDF if you don't use XSLT?

Comment: @MartinHonnen I included xsl because I extract xml data with it to html, including the barcode, and I was hoping the xsl syntax won't confuse those who don't know of it yet. Thanks again Martin, I'll contact the authors of the software to see what's up.